# Nasty noise from chain device

Tags: chainring, drivetrain, noise, downhill

Hi I've purchased and fitted a superstar components plasma chain device in my specialized big hit. It makes a terrible noise and I really don't see why. As far as I can see I've set it up correctly with the spacers. There is space either side of the chain in the upper guide but a really nasty noise when pedaling. I presume the noise is from the lower roller as when this is removed the noise is gone. The chain seems well aligned in the device with a 36t chain ring. I can't see where the issue is. The noise sounds like the derailleur is badly out of time but I know it's not. Any ideas would be a great help.

Comment: Have you checked that the chain is running correctly trough the rear derailleur? Some cages have little knobs close to the jockey wheels and it is easy to fit the chain such they would rattle over them. A photo of your setup would help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I've tried to upload photos but don't seem to get anywhere. My bike is set up with 1x10 Shimano zee short cage DH derailleur and 36t chainring. I didn't open the chain to fit the chain device I just slipped it off the chain ring and removed the crankset. Without the lower roller on the chain device there is no sound and gears change smoothly. As soon as I fit the lower roller onto the chain device the noise is rancid. Not substantial when back pedal but when pedaling as normal sounds really loud. I'm sure I've got the spacing right as the upper cage of the device is perfect. I've checked the l

Comment: Feel free to upload your photos to imgur.com or any hosting thing and then we can edit them into your question.  New users are limited by low reputation score.

Comment: Is it possible you have a bad one from new?  Does the lower roller feel bad/crunchy/notchy/stiff  if you spin it by hand ?

Comment: It's possible I suppose. I've taken the lower roller slider off removed the roller and had a look but the bearing is smooth and has no side to side play